# Emailing Dynamically Created JS Form Data

Tags: javascript, forms, email

Firstly, I'm super new to JavaScript. I have created a form the dynamically adds html inputs and selection boxes based on the number a user enters.

I am now trying to figure out how to retrieve the data inputted into this dynamically created form.

I understand that JS can't email.

Is there a way around this? An alternative that would allow me to get a user's inputs? Maybe some simple additional language I can use to accomplish this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
};


window.onload = function() {
  $("add-number").onclick = function() {
    var hatVar = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var numberOfHats = parseInt(hatVar);

    var i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < numberOfHats; i++) {
      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Last Name" + (i + 1)));
      var lastName = document.createElement("input");
      lastName.className = "Last-Name";
      lastName.type = "text";
      container.appendChild(lastName);
      container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

      var dropOp = ["S/M", "L/XL"];

      container.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" Size" + (i + 1)));
      var size = document.createElement("select");
      size.className = "size";
      size.options[size.options.length] = new Option('S/M', 'Value1');
      size.options[size.options.length] = new Option('L/XL', 'Value2');
      container.appendChild(size);
      container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    }

    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "Submit Order";
    btn.className = "btn";
    container.appendChild(btn);

    btn.onclick = function() {
      console.log(lastName.value);
    }


  }

};
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 450px;
  padding: 0 2em 1em;
}

h1 {
  color: black;
}

label {
  width: 11em;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}

input {
  margin-left: 0em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

fieldset {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

#filldetails {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ABIT Hat Order</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hats.css">
  <script src="hats.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1>ABIT Hats</h1>
    <p> Please enter the number of hats you would like to order.</p>
    <input type="text" name="number" id="number"><br>
    <input type="button" name="add-number" id="add-number" value="Submit">
    <div id="container" />
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You would normally create a little backend (server-side) script to do the emailing for you. A  popular choice is php. You'd have a little php script that takes your form data and constructs/sends an email with it. You will need to look into sending requests to/from the server (such as using ajax). There are many tutorials online for sending form data to server-side scripts for emailing.

Comment: To add on to @ChrisCousins comment, since you're working with javascript anyway, you should look into using node.js for your backend server.

Comment: Even if the browser API would allow to connect to a mail server you still not want to do that. You need to do a bunch of data verification and escaping before you compose the data you receive from the user into an email. Otherwise your form will be abused to send spam, phishing or other fraud mails. And the only way to do that in a aomewhat reasonable is serverside.